# Order of displaying labels within a layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

How do I choose the order which labels are drawn, within a layer? I am using label classes but I don't want my points drawn in the order of the label class. My points are numbered and I want to ensure that the lowest numbered ones always sit above higher numbered ones.

Comment: Can you please provide further information on what you're trying to achieve? Have you explored using [label classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s80000000v000000)?

Comment: Is it useful if you use several label classes for each group of points(for example you divide points into 10 groups depending on the number ranges),and then use label priority ranking and label wight ranking button to make a proper order for label classes.so that determines which group should be labeled first or can be overlapped by other labels.Sure it can be done programmaticaly even it is not recommended.